# Gutenberg blocks - print attributes query (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'd like to display a button in my plugin that creates a custom Wordpress block. I have a problem, I cannot display an attribute from the query array:

**block.json:**

```
"hero_button_1": {
        "type": "array",
        "source": "query",
        "selector": "a",
        "query": {
            "url": {
                "type": "string",
                "source": "attribute",
                "selector": "a",
                "attribute": "href"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "source": "attribute",
                "selector": "a",
                "attribute": "title"
            },
            "text": {
                "type": "array",
                "source": "children",
                "selector": "a"
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit.js**

```
     const buttonHeroURL = ( newURL ) => {
        setAttributes( { 
           hero_button_1: {
            url: newURL
           }
        } )
     } 

    
     <RichText
        {...blockProps}
        tagName="a"
        onChange={buttonHeroURL}
        allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic']}
        value={attributes.hero_button_1.url}
        placeholder={__('Adress url button')} 
     />
```

**save.js**

```
     <RichText.Content 
        { ...blockProps } 
        tagName="a"
        className={"mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 sm:mt-5 sm:text-lg sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto 
        md:mt-5 md:text-xl lg:mx-0"}
        value={ attributes.hero_button_1.url } 
     />
```

I need to create custom buttons in which it will be possible to specify the url and the button name on the backend side of Wordpress.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code (i am assuming you have the base construct working):

```
<RichText
        {...blockProps}
        tagName="a"
        onChange={(value) => {
          setAttributes({hero_button_1: value})
        }}
        allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic']}
        value={hero_button_1}
        placeholder={__('Adress url button')} 
     />
```

This will set the value on the `hero_button_1` directly. If you want it inside as an object, you'll have to deal with creating a JSON String.

For this to work you'll also have to get your `attributes` and the `setAttributes` in your edit function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/

Similar to this example of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544454/7262739