# Gutenberg custom block - media upload (get alt image)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Hi i don't know how to get alt image by media upload in gutenberg custom block.

```
edit.js:
function selectImage(value) {
    console.log(value);
    setAttributes({
        imgUrl: value.sizes.full.url,
    })
}

     <MediaUploadCheck>
        <MediaUpload
            onSelect={selectImage}
            allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
            value={ 1 }
            render={ ({open}) => {
                return <img 
                    src={attributes.imgUrl}
                    onClick={open}
                    />;
            }}
        />
     </MediaUploadCheck>

save.js:
<div className='flex columns-xl justify-center items-center content-center'>
   <img className='max-w-sm' src={attributes.imgUrl} alt=""/>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with alt images:

edit.js

```
        <InspectorControls>
        <PanelBody icon={image} title="Alt do HeroImage" initialOpen={false}>
            <TextControl
                label="hero image alt:"
                value={attributes.imgAlt}
                onChange={ ( val ) => setAttributes( { imgAlt: val } ) }
            />
        </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>

     <MediaUploadCheck>
        <MediaUpload
            onSelect={selectImage}
            allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
            value={ 1 }
            render={ ({open}) => {
                return <img 
                    src={attributes.imgUrl}
                    onClick={open}
                    />;
            }}
        />
     </MediaUploadCheck>
```

save.js

```
export default function save( { attributes } ) {
const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
return (
  <img className='classhere' src={attributes.imgUrl} alt={attributes.imgAlt}/>
);
}
```

block.json

```
"attributes": {
    "imgUrl": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "imgAlt": {
      "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find it in the `attributes` variable. log the `attributes` variable in the console and you'll see what other values you have in it.

Comment: if he doesn't "get" the attributes variable from somewhere, it will not simply show up when doing this.

Comment: I've read that somewhere before as well. Do you have time to provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it like this to get the `title` for example:

```
edit: ({attributes, setAttributes}) => {
        const {
            title,
            media
        } = attributes;

        return (<>{title}</>)
}
```

setAttributes is used to "set" them with new values.

So for example:

```
setAttributes({title: 'my new title'})
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

@Vijay Hardaha is correct in that with newer versions of Gutenberg, MediaUpload [returns an image as an object](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-placeholder/README.md#onselect) with a lot of information, including alt, id, and url. In my script, notice the console.log just before the return. Once an image is selected, it will will show you the object details.

In this example I am using the [placeholder similar to this post](https://gutenberghub.com/create-scrollable-image-gallery-block/) and I am extracting the image src and alt [based on this post](https://davidyeiser.com/tutorials/wordpress-dynamic-gutenberg-block-code-snippets).

**Note**: That second post also explains how to replace MediaPlaceholder with the selected image using the "hasImages" const. The original is a gallery so it returns an array of objects. I only wanted one image so I changed it.

**Inside of edit.js**

```
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const hasImages = attributes.images.id !== undefined;
    console.log(attributes.images);
    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            {hasImages && (
                <MediaUpload
                    allowedTypes={['image']}
                    multiple={false}
                    value={attributes.images ? attributes.images.id : ''}
                    onSelect={(newImages) => setAttributes({ images: newImages })}
                    render={({ open }) => (
                        <div className="image">
                            <figure>
                                <img src={attributes.images.url} alt={attributes.images.alt} />
                            </figure>
                            <div>
                                <Button onClick={() => setAttributes({ images: '' })} className="button">Remove</Button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
            )}
            {!hasImages && (
                <MediaPlaceholder
                    icon={<BlockIcon icon="format-gallery" />}
                    labels={{
                        title: "Placeholder Title",
                        instructions: "Add a most excellent image.",
                    }}
                    onSelect={(newImages) => setAttributes({ images: newImages })}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Inside of block.json**, my images attribute is type "object":

```
"attributes": {
    "images": {
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!